# Can't RDP or FTP to Azure VM via Site-to-Site VPN

Tags: azure, rdp, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn

I have a VM (Windows Server 2019) that's running in Azure and I want to be able to 'control' the VM via our on-premise network. I have a Fortinet firewall configured to make an IPSEC-tunnel to an Azure VPN gateway. So far so good, the tunnel is active and I can already do some things, but not everything:

- I can ping my Azure VM (after adding a firewall rule on the VM) from my internal network (192.168.10.*).
- I have full access from my Azure VM to my internal network: can RDP to on-premise servers etc.
- I cannot RDP to the VM from my local network. Just doesn't find it.
- As a test I started an FTP server on the VM. If I do a 'telnet 10.10.0.4 21' it does connect, it just doesn't go any further
- Same exact thing with an IIS website test

What it looks like to me is that I can reach the VM server, but the replies don't get correctly sent back.

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Comment: Sounds like an NSG blocks the traffic, how does the inbound and outbound rules look?

Comment: I have the standard rules for the NSG of the VM. So there's an inbound and outbound rule with source and destination "VirtualNetwork" which allows all traffic to the vnet. If I test the RDP port in network watcher it's all green. Really weird!

If I try to connect with FTP I get:
- connecting tot 10.10.0.4:21
- connection succesful, awaiting welcome message
- timeout